# change of value format to standard 30-second format in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I'm looking to format non-standard change of value format data (reading only when `Value` changes) to a standard 30-second interval format.

**What I have: `df`:**

```
Timestamp   Value
6/26/2018 0:00:06   10
6/26/2018 0:01:06   15
6/26/2018 0:02:15   20
```

and `dput`:

```
structure(list(Timestamp = c("6/26/2018 0:00:06", "6/26/2018 0:01:06", 
"6/26/2018 0:02:15"), Value = c(10L, 15L, 20L)), .Names = c("Timestamp", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**what I'd like** `formatted_df`:

```
Timestamp   Value
6/26/2018 0:00:30   10
6/26/2018 0:01:00   10
6/26/2018 0:01:30   15
6/26/2018 0:02:00   15
6/26/2018 0:02:30   20
```

**My attempt:**

Using functions from `lubridate` and `dplyr`, I've got intervals at multiples of 30-seconds, but it doesn't *standardize* to 30 seconds:

```
formatted <- df %>% mutate(Timestamp_Date = as.POSIXct(Timestamp, tz = "US/Eastern", usetz = TRUE, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                           rounded_timestamp = ceiling_date(Timestamp_Date, unit = "30 seconds"))
```

with `formatted`:

```
Timestamp   Value   Timestamp_Date  rounded_timestamp
6/26/2018 0:00:06   10  6/26/2018 0:00:06   6/26/2018 0:00:30
6/26/2018 0:01:06   15  6/26/2018 0:01:06   6/26/2018 0:01:30
6/26/2018 0:02:15   20  6/26/2018 0:02:15   6/26/2018 0:02:30
```

I think `lubridate` and `dplyr` would be useful here, but I'd bet `data.table` could do it.

Comment: You can use the data.table rolling join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data.table` rolling join.

```
library(data.table)

#convert df into data.table and Timestamp into POSIX format
setDT(df)[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")]

#create the intervals of 30seconds according to needs
tstmp <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-06-26 00:00:30", tz=""), 
    as.POSIXct("2018-06-26 00:02:30", tz=""), 
    by="30 sec")

#rolling join between intervals and df
df[.(Timestamp=tstmp), on=.(Timestamp), roll=Inf]
```

output:

```
             Timestamp Value
1: 2018-06-26 00:00:30    10
2: 2018-06-26 00:01:00    10
3: 2018-06-26 00:01:30    15
4: 2018-06-26 00:02:00    15
5: 2018-06-26 00:02:30    20
```

For more info, please read the `roll` argument in `?data.table`